# Comparing signed and unsigned numbers

Tags: c

When for example saying if (-1>2). This condition is true because the signed value (-1) is converted to an unsigned value I know that. But What I want to know is how is it converted? And if it's value is changed, what it will be?

Comment: Depends on the machine, but almost all modern ones use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: If your compiler says -1 > 2 you should switch compilers

Comment: @Kevin Ok. If we converted (-1) which is (11111111) by two's complement, it will be (00000001) which is (1) in decimal. Then the condition will be (1>2) which should be false. But when I try that in a program, it shows that it is true. Why?

Comment: There is no need to convert anything, the expression (-1 > 2) evaluates to false, the literal constants are interpreted as signed integers.

Comment: @user3417785 -1 -> 0b11111111, correct. I have no idea where you're getting 0b00000001 from. 0b11111111 = 1023, not 1. Therefore -1 > 2 = 1023 > 2, which is true. As others have pointed out, only if one of them is unsigned (-1 > 2u).

Comment: What about if the (2) is stored in an unsigned variable and the (-1) is stored in a signed one? @amdn

Comment: You already know that -1 is 11111111...1111 in two's complement.  Casting doesn't change the bits, it changes the interpretation.  1111111...1111 is 2^32-1 as an unsigned value (assuming 32 bits).

Comment: Ah, that's a different story, see http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/08/a-tutorial-on-signed-and-unsigned-integers/

Comment: Ok. I understood now. Thanks all of you guys for responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When for example saying if (-1>2). This condition is true because the
>   signed value (-1) is converted to an unsigned value I know that.

No, it's not.

Both integer constants (to be precise, as pointed in @KeithThompson's comment the former operand is constant expression, as `-` in this context acts as unary operator, that changes sign of its operand) have type `int` (i.e. `signed int`), thus as @amdn pointed out there is nothing to convert (as operands' types are simply the same), The result of `if`'s condition evaluation is `0` (or false).

You probably meant `-1 > 2U`, which is kind of different story. Due to *usual arithmetic conversions* rules (colloquially called as integer promotions), `int`'s operand is promoted to `unsigned` type, yielding some big number, that is likely to be larger than `2U` (or simply 2 in the purely mathematical sense). More specfically both `unsigned` and `int` types are of the same rank, but due to these rules in such situation signed counterpart (i.e. operand) is promoted to unsigned.

Comment: @mafso: Thank you for valuable comment!

Comment: Yes, both integer constants `1` and `2` are of type `int`. But `-1` is not an integer constant; it's a constant expression consisting of the constant `1` with the unary `-` operator applied to it -- and it's also of type `int`.